# Grails urlmappings, can one prefix urlmappings?

Tags: grails, url-mapping

So for instance, say i have an API on a webapp, and i wish to use the same controllers and actions in the API as the rest of the webapp.

In my urlmappings file i have

```
"/api/$version/$apiKey/$controller/$acion/$id?"
```

and i also have a mapping like this:

```
"/blog/$year/$month/$day/$action" {
   controller = 'blog'
 }
```

Now the question is, can i somehow prefix the api urlmapping to the blog urlmapping so i can benefit from the $year, $month, $day variables? in such a way that a GET request to the following url would be valid:

```
GET /api/0.1/bs23mk4m2n4k/blog/2001/01/05/list
```

or am i forced to do the following request instead?

```
GET /api/0.1/bs23mk4m2n4k/blog/list?year=2004&month=01&day=05
```

Need help from an urlmappings GURU or a groovy runtime urlmappings maniuplation WIZARD :)

I want a solution that can reuse existing non-api urmappings, instead of having to redeclare them with the api path as a prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have an ApiController strip off the api parameters, then redirect to the blog controller.  For example:

```
"/api/$version/$apiKey/$rest**" {
     controller:'api'
     action:'default'
}


import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
class ApiController {
    def grailsUrlMappingsHolder

    def default = {
        // validate apiKey, etc
        WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(request, response, grailsUrlMappingsHolder.match("/${params.rest}"))
    }
}
```

The API controller has access to the version and apiKey params, and passes on the rest of the params to be processed by the blog controller's UrlMapping.

Comment: this will cause a 302 redirect on all api calls :( not a good thing... but it will however work...

Comment: Updated my answer to do an internal forward rather than a 302 redirect.

Comment: Looks good, i will test it out. Would however be best if i could keep the additional class ApiController out of the picture aswell as the forward statement. But this is a definite solution! thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know why filters are run twice when doing an internal forward. is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use embedded variables. Check the url mapping reference: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.4 URL Mappings

just add the following mapping:

```
static mappings = {
   "/api/$version/$apiKey/$controller/$year/$month/$day/$action"()
}
```

now you can use this url for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/0.1/bs23mk4m2n4k/blog/2001/01/05/list
```

now you get redirected to the list action in the blog controller.
there you can use params to show the parameters from the url (as defined in the mapping).

ex.

```
params.version
```

Comment: "I want a solution that can reuse existing non-api urmappings, instead of having to redeclare them with the api path as a prefix."

Comment: ok. missed this in your question. but why is it a problem to declare this mapping also? what is the benefit to use the existing mappings?

Comment: but you have two different url patterns so two mappings are needed. they are not "identical". How many url mappings did you declare then. Maybe I get the problem when you post more of your url mapping.

Comment: Look at ataylors answer. His answer does exactly what i want. With his solution both the /api urlmapping AND the "normal" mapping is executed, w/o having to declare any more /api urlmappings.. The only thing negative with his solution is that he is using a forward() call, which i have had my differences with in the past. What i originally wanted was for the urlmappings to be smart and understand that the /api urlmapping should be prefixed on all non-api urlmappings effectively creating what you have described in your solution. However, this shouldn't have to be done manually.

Answer (score -1):

I had somewhat the same problem, solved it using named url mapping: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4.9%20Named%20URL%20Mappings

Hope this helps!

in urlMapping:

```
name blogWithYear:"/api/$version/$apiKey/$controller/$year/$month/$day":{
controller = 'blog'
action = 'youraction'
}

<g:link mapping="blogWithYear" params="[$version:'0.1', ....., '$year: 2011']">
Show blog
</g:link>
```

With g:link you can now compile the url however you want, adding parameters.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how this benefits my problem?

Comment: this is not what im looking for. I want to avoid hardcoding the urlmappings twice (once for web and once for api).